# Sysstat versions

Tags: 16.04

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. I'd like to update the sysstat package to version 11.6 as runs on Ubuntu 18.04. Is it possible to upgrade the sysstat version on 16.04 ?

Comment: is compiling from source viable for you?

Comment: I suppose so - I have not compiled source in the past. But would be willing to try.

Comment: also is upgrading ubuntu versions viable? I get that this is distant server machine but 16,04 is really starting to get dated. if you have full rights, then you should be able to upgrade from the command line smoothly. you'll have to uninstall the apps  you use preemptively then reinstall them after upgrade but everything will be smoother coasting from there. you won't get one of those "no release" situations anymore.

Comment: I don't get to choose the version of the OS - I have some influence on utilities. I like the new features in sysstat 11.6 and above. Ubuntu 18.04 only supports sysstat 11.6.1. Instructions with the tar bundles leave a lot undefined - dependencies, etc. Seems like it should be far easier to update utility versions for better monitoring.